# What are common file extensions for web programming languages?

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages, file-extension

What file extensions are used most commonly by different languages? Please don't put source file names (like .java) but rather extensions that would be present in a URL for rendered pages.

Here is my (alphabetized) list so far

- ASP Classic
- asp
- ASP.NET
- aspx
- axd
- asx
- asmx
- ashx
- CSS
- css
- Coldfusion
- cfm
- Erlang
- yaws
- Flash
- swf
- HTML
- html
- htm
- xhtml
- jhtml
- Java
- jsp
- jspx
- wss
- do
- action
- JavaScript
- js
- Perl
- pl
- PHP
- php
- php4
- php3
- phtml
- Python
- py
- Ruby
- rb
- rhtml
- SSI
- shtml
- TS
- XML
- xml
- rss
- svg
- Other (C, perl etc.)
- cgi
- dll

Any more? I'll keep updating this based on comments. Largest correct additions (or deletions) is the accepted answer.

Aside: This is for comparing language use online: http://blog.paulisageek.com/2009/10/file-extensions-on-internet.html

Comment: shouldn't this be in community-wiki ?

Comment: sure, how does that work? Check the box?

Comment: What about asa and asax?  Not typically extensions that the user will see.

Comment: asax looks like mostly misconfigured servers giving out source data : http://www.google.com/search?q=ext%3Aasax

Comment: You have .rhtml listed for Ruby, but it could potentially be .html.erb.  I didn't add this as an answer because you already commented you would add this.

Comment: Your survey would appear to be highly flawed, purely because [as you have yourself accepted], there are many, many, many web sites which use a URI structure that doesn't expose a file extension, and because the file extension can't be relied upon to be true.

Comment: .erb for ruby is not right because it is like "java": it's just an extension for the server side.

Comment: urls have no relation to underlying technologies, and if you're basing a survey on this, it will have no value.  as an example, what language does `dll` correspond to?  http://www.allmusic.com/cg/amg.dll.

Comment: Why would this matter in any way whatsoever? The filenames in use are completely up to the content authors and should make no difference to you, no?

Comment: actually I used this to configure my mac which was annoyingly using dreamweaver to open *everything*. Also I don't think it's relevant what servers are configured to show in their URLs - the question is a list of commonly used file extensions, not a list of commonly used URL configurations.

Comment: does anyone have this list?

Comment: Link is broken. Please update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add there:

- ASP.NET

  - .axd
  - .asx
  - .asmx
  - .ashx
  - .aspx

Comment: No - completely different apart from the branding.

Comment: If you're going to list .asmx for ASP.NET web services, then you should also list .svc for ASP.NET hosted WCF services.

Answer (score 14):

Keep in mind that good URL design will completely hide any underlying file types.

Comment: Yup, this is why it is only approximate. A lot of people still don't do that.

Comment: now a days there are no extensions for increasing readability of the URL, check stackoverflow URL

Comment: correct. which is why i'm doing this study now before it is too late :)

Comment: That depends. For user endpoints, I agree. Something like `example.com/my-article` looks better than `example.com/my-article.html`. For internal references that only concern machines, however, something like `example.com/stylesheet` has no real advantages over `example.com/stylesheet.css`, and does in fact have some (albeit minor) disadvantages.

Comment: This answer is absolutely correct!  But also keep in mind &mdash; being able to treat any sort of runnable-script extension as your actual native one is best at accomplishing this (imho), hence the question.

Answer (score 6):

I have created a Github gist that contains a list of programming languages and their extensions, here is a subset of the data included in the gist file:

```
{
  "name":"CoffeeScript",
  "type":"programming",
  "extensions":[
     ".coffee",
     "._coffee",
     ".cake",
     ".cjsx",
     ".cson",
     ".iced"
   ]
  },{
  "name":"ColdFusion",
  "type":"programming",
  "extensions":[
     ".cfm",
     ".cfml"
  ]}
```

I hope it is helpful.

[languages.json](https://gist.github.com/aymen-mouelhi/82c93fbcd25f091f2c13faa5e0d61760).

Comment: Whoa, what a tremendous amount of work!  Great answer, upvoted!

Answer (score 2):

- `.action` — struts2
- `.do`     — struts1
- `.xml`    — XML
- `.rss`    — RSS feeds
- `.atom`   — Atom feeds(RSS)

(no extension) -- used now a days to increase readability of the URL, check stackoverflow URL

Answer (score 1):

`.yaws` (Erlang Yaws Web Server)

Answer (score 1):

`.js`, `.html`, `.htm`, `.xhtml` probably deserve a nod.

Comment: Totally right, thanks for your addition.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby on Rails also uses the following internally for templates (files that are mostly HTML or JavaScript). So they're not really public facing, and are transparent to the end user/robot.

- `.html.erb`
- `.erb`
- `.rjs`

Used to be that most [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) scripts were written in Perl.

Comment: I'm tentative about adding CGI to perl. I'll do more research. But I added those for ruby.

Comment: Upvoted!  Good answer, nobody else mentions `erb`.  But imho, I think a file ending in `.html.erb` is technically just an `erb` file, based on normal extension rules (I'd list it in parens near `.erb`, but it shouldn't be its own item, again imho), thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension you forgot:

- `.adp` — [**AOLServer**](http://aolserver.sourceforge.net/docs/devel/tcl/adp-overview.html) using TCL

Comment: now you're pulling my leg. there are 0 of those online http://www.google.com/search?q=ext%3A.adp

Comment: AOLServer developers are, apparently, better at mapping clean URLs to the underlying pages I guess.

Comment: Upvoted!  It's actually *extremely rare*, but about [50% of the URL's using `.adp` as an extension](https://www.google.com/search?q=filetype%3Aadp) are indeed valid script pages.   Like this really weird site [forest.cpast.org](https://forest.cpast.org/Articles/fetch.adp?topicnum=61).

Answer (score 1):

Ruby also tended to use .rhtml in the past.

Stellent uses the .hcsp extension for its page templates.

I believe Django uses .dtl.

Comment: I've never heard of anyone using `.dtl` for Django templates.  The overwhelmingly common standard seems to be using the extension of whatever kind of file the template will be rendered to.  If it's producing a css file, it's `mytemplate.css`, if it's making an html file then `mytemplate.html`, etc.

Comment: [**`.hscp`**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21043_01/doc.1111/e10807/c04_look_nav002.htm#:~:text=A%20Hypertext%20Content%20Server%20Page,Server%20through%20an%20HCSF%20page.) and [**`.dtl`**](https://www.filetypeadvisor.com/extension/dtl) are both totally valid, and not mentioned elsewhere, upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

IE specific strangeness:

- `.hta` — html application
- `.htc` — html components, allows you to alter IE behavior at runtime, from you website!

Also XML:

- `.svg` — it's not just an image format!

Comment: Good answer, upvoted!  `.htc` isn't mentioned elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

-SSI (Server Side Includes), use the extension `.shtml`

Answer (score 0):

.aspx 
.asp
.css

Answer (score 0):

**REBOL** tends to use **.r**

But **.cgi** is also used by some for REBOL CGI scripts.

Comment: most of the .r don't look like rebol to me. http://www.google.com/search?q=ext%3Ar . Do they look right to you?

Comment: I think those are just coincedences with people ending usernames with '.r'.

Comment: even on the pages way down, they still look like garbage. sorry.

Comment: Not all [b].r[/]b is [b]REBOL[/b]. But much [b]REBOL CGI[/]b is [b].r[/b].

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET needs a couple more, but I'm not sure this is exhaustive:

- aspx
- ascx
- asmx (web services)

Comment: added ascx. does the set look comprehensive now?

Comment: However you won't see the .ascx in a URL.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few of the commonly-used (but rarely enforced) extensions for some CSS dialects:

- `.hss` for [hss style sheets](http://ncannasse.fr/projects/hss)
- `.sass` for [sass style sheets](http://sass-lang.com/)
- `.less` for [less css style sheets](http://lesscss.org/)
- `.ccss` or `.pcss` for [clever css style sheets](http://sandbox.pocoo.org/clevercss/)

Comment: interesting, I've never heard of them. They look more like source files than extensions of actual pages on the next. Am it correct?

Comment: **@Paul Tarjan:** Yes, that's what they are, but so are `py` and `rb`, so that's what I figured you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Going old school: **.cgi**

Typically written in **C** or **Perl**

Comment: heh, but what language? perl?

Answer (score 0):

.java .cs and .i_am_kidding_i_read_the_question.

On the serious side, `swf` (Flash) get hidden by the JS that loads them, generally, but they are extensions usually seen by the client. This is a limit case because it's not like JPEG (doesn't allow for web programming) nor like Javascript. But then, neither is PHP/ASP/JSP because from the client side it's just markup :)

Answer (score 0):

`.json` has become popular as a data xfer format

`.png` `.jpg` `.gif` are the most common graphics, but there are others.

Also video extensions

Answer (score 0):

- .cs ----> C#
- .kt ----> Kotlin

Comment: Aren't these source code file extensions for compiled languages?  [**KT**](https://fileinfo.com/extension/kt) and [**CS**](https://docs.fileformat.com/programming/cs/)?  I wouldn't imagine these would ever be the extension of a web page script.