# Distinguish HTML documents by URL suffix

Tags: html, http, url, language-agnostic

What a browser receives as HTML file can have many different filename extensions on the path: `.html`, `.htm`, `/`, `.php`, `.asp`, `.stm`, `.cgi`, etc.

Is there a way to **distinguish, from only the request URL, whether it points to a HTML document or some additional data** (f.ex. `.png`, `.css`, `.js`, ...)? This should be determined *at the time of the request*, so waiting for Content-Type is not an option.

#### HTML URLs

`google.com/`, `stackoverflow.com`, `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator`, `https://www.google.de/search?q=content-length`, `http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html`

#### non-HTML URLs

`http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded`,  `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js`,  `http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=aaf07438bdbd`

Maybe filtering the non-html parts (for example, by `js`, `css`, `png`, `jpg`, ...) would work. An alternative would be to filter by [What are common file extensions for web programming languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614520/what-are-common-file-extensions-for-web-programming-languages) and include directories and domains.

It must not be perfect, close enough would be good.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to distinguish, from only the request URL, whether it
>   points to a HTML document or some additional data (f.ex. .png, .css,
>   .js, ...)? This should be determined at the time of the request, so
>   waiting for Content-Type is not an option.

**No, this is not possible.**

The webserver can do anything it wants in response to a request.

Some responses can be static, i.e. files on disk (but even then, the extension is no guarantee for the real contents of the file) - others can be totally dynamic, and only the server decides what kind of data to return (it could even return a .jpg file in response to a .html request -- or the opposite could happen a lot in the real world: a .jpg url that returns a html page with a download link for that jpg).

A lot of url's don't even have an extension, so checking the extension in general is no solution.

The best (soonest) way is to look at the `Content-Type` header field (assuming it corresponds with the data).

If the client doesn't want to download the full response, only to check the `Content-Type`, a `HEAD` request can be made, which will only return the `HTTP headers`.

Answer (score 2):

No.

URLs are, once you hit the path segment, entirely arbitrary.

Sometimes the URL will include something which happens to match a filename on the HTTP server's hard disk. **Sometimes** that filename will give a clue about what kind of data is in it. Often it will give a clue about how the server will execute a program which will generate content of any kind.

The authoritative description of what an HTTP resource is is the Content-Type response header (and sometimes servers give wrong information there anyway).

Comment: Thank you. So you have seen f.ex. stylesheets and pictures which do not contain the appropriate suffix?

Comment: I've generated both images and CSS (and JS for that matter) from server side code with extensions such as `.php` and `.cgi`. and with nothing that looks like a file extension at all.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible (assuming you're looking for something reliable).

In general, the format of a URI is independent of the media type of the resource it identifies. That's how the web works.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? Have you tried it? Any reference on why it would not work?

Comment: In general, the format of a URI is independent of the media type of the resource it identifies. That's how the web works.

Answer (score -1):

The below answer is deprecated. In Python, there is [mimetypes.py](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mimetypes.html) in the standard library, which does exactly that.

#### Old answer

As a bit of reasoning: URLs containing file extensions like `.html` are implementation specifics. When you change from `cgi` to, whatever, you would be forced to either abandon the URL, breaking links, or keep an incorrect version around. See also

- [Semantic URL Wiki Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL) and
- [Cool URIs don't change](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html).

Comment: mimetypes.py  doesn't do that. It maps file extensions to mime types. As the "Old answer" says, URLs don't have useful file extensions, so mimetypes.py doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Quentin: The first sentence of [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mimetypes.html): "The mimetypes module converts between a filename **or URL** and the MIME type associated with the filename extension."

Comment: That's a fancy claim it makes, and as this answer points out, largely incorrect.