# why Websites are in different extension names?

Tags: calabash-android, lxml.html

can anyone please tell me why websites will be having the extension with a different name such as .html,.com,.net,.php,.asp?

I found some info on .html but I didn't find for other extensions.

Thanks

Comment: These are file extensions not website extensions. Depending on the operating system of the webserver and the language and technologies used to create them you will have these different file extensions. In modern websites you will not see any extension but does not mean the files don't have it. 

Here is an iterating similar question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614520/what-are-common-file-extensions-for-web-programming-languages

Comment: These are called "handler" so the advice is to do some research on web server handlers and see how that applies to your server. And then come back to the appropriate Stack Exchange site if you a specific question. Hint: Stack Overflow is not for this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

It mainly depends on the way the website was written. Web browsers are relatively smart beasts, and they know how to display and interact with a number of different interchange formats.

For example, php code allows you to do certain things that are not available in html, but could be produced in html with the use of javascript. It just depends on the server and the stack used by any particular website, which technologies they will choose to deploy.